# Performance concerns of scheduling a large quantity of Hangfire jobs

Tags: c#, .net-core, scheduling, jobs, hangfire

We have an API built with .Net Core 3.1, hosted on an AppService plan in Azure. Recently we got a customer requirement of scheduling and sending out e-mail reminders. We've looked into Hangfire and it seems like a good fit for our scheduling needs.

We estimate that there could possible be thousands of jobs scheduled at the same time in the future. The maximum concurrent jobs are currently set to 20.

Is it a bad idea to run this in the same project as the API? Are there any performance concerns that we should be aware of in this arrangement?